Was the Mickey Mouse Easter egg in the original Tron movie?
I re-watched the original Tron movie, around the time that Tron Legacy was released, and noticed an Easter egg.

 When Flynn is on the Solar Sailer with Tron and Yori, there's a shot from above where the ground/circuit below them appears to show Mickey's face. You can make out the nose, and most of both ears.

Was this Easter egg in the original Tron theatre release, back in 1982?

While this doesn't answer the question, it's worth noting that it's very common for Disney to hide Mickey's silhouette inside their properties - Wikipedia claims there are over 1,000 instances.

https://i.sstatic.net/OltJRav1.jpg yes. Apparently its in Proberts original storyboards too.

Why wouldn't it be?

@BCdotWEB - Because lots of films get remastered and new crap added

Home VHS version with hidden mickey https://youtu.be/U80QdvksHhw?si=sSQ-mbb4cbl6DNvb

@blobbymcblobby - Post that as an answer. Maybe find a better version though
